# Returning Error while dynamically creating database

Tags: vb.net

Net and i am trying to create a database depending on the excel files in a folder. I did some based on my current knowledge so far and it is returning error. Is this method correct or is there any more efficient way in creating a database

```
 Try
        Dim pro() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
        For Each p As Process In pro
            p.Kill()
        Next
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=Localhost;Database=aj; Uid=root; pwd=;")
        con.Open()
        Dim filename As String
        Dim oex As Object
        oex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Dim obfldr As Object
        Dim fldrobj As Object
        Dim fs As Object
        fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        obfldr = fs.GetFolder("C:\New folder\Release")
        For Each fldrobj In obfldr.files
            ln = fldrobj.Name
            MsgBox(ln)
            filename = FileNameWithoutExtension(fldrobj.name)
            MsgBox(filename)
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS'" & filename & "'", con)
            Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim read As MySqlDataReader
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Next fldrobj
 Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Can anyone help me out with this problem that am having?

Comment: you might start by telling us where the code throws an exception and what the exception is

Comment: @Carsten    `read = cmd.ExecuteReader`

Comment: At that line it throwed exception

Comment: well yeah - that's reasonable - you'll want the [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: also you don' t need neither the DataAdapter nor the DataReader here

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: No, Tried still throwing error

Comment: Is there any other way to create a database better way to create a database?

Comment: It is throwing syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code like this solved the issue i had. And i also had to remove spaces and colons from the sql statement or it will return error

```
 For Each fldrobj In obfldr.files
            ln = fldrobj.Name
            filename = FileNameWithoutExtension(fldrobj.name)
            filename = filename.Replace("-", "")
            filename = filename.Replace(" ", "")
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " & filename, con)
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Next fldrobj
```